# Update record with data from another table (but lookup table contains duplicate records)

Tags: sql, plsql

I have one record where I want to update a field with the data from an identical field in another table. Problem is that the lookup table contains duplicate records so I just want to bring data from the first matched record.

Here's what I have right now but I get this error:

> too many values

My query is:

```
UPDATE T_TABLE1 T1 
SET T1.UPDATEFIELD =  (SELECT DISTINCT(T2.itemtag), MAX(T2.UPDATEFIELD) 
                       FROM T_TABLE2 T2  
                       WHERE T2.ITEMTAG = T1.ITEMTAG 
                       GROUP BY T2.itemtag)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this:

```
UPDATE T_TABLE1 T1 
SET T1.UPDATEFIELD =  (SELECT MAX(T2.UPDATEFIELD) 
                       FROM T_TABLE2 T2  
                       WHERE T2.ITEMTAG = T1.ITEMTAG 
                       GROUP BY T2.itemtag)
```

Comment: only problem is when I add the criteria "WHERE T2.ITEMTAG = T1.ITEMTAG  OR T2.ITEMTAG = T1.END1 OR T2.ITEMTAG = T1.END2" the query runs indefinately

Comment: How many rows are in the tables? Or's can be really expensive to run.

Comment: 60000 in one and 27000 in the other

Comment: The number of rows coupled with the multiple OR match is the most likely cause of the query running indefinitely. I'd look at changing my table design to eliminate the need to do the OR's or you need to change the query to eliminate the OR's.

Answer (score 0):

You are selecting two columns which is causing the problem;

```
UPDATE T_TABLE1 T1 
SET T1.UPDATEFIELD =  (SELECT MAX(T2.UPDATEFIELD) 
                       FROM T_TABLE2 T2  
                       WHERE T2.ITEMTAG = T1.ITEMTAG 
                       GROUP BY T2.itemtag)
```

Hope this help.